# Reflection Added to db but file does not exit

Tags: impresspages

File is relative to /file/repository/AutoSalon/hasi/BB_Light_House_8.png

```
ipFileUrl(ipReflection('AutoSalon/'.$user['username'].'/'.$value['photo1'],$opti‌​ons,'thumb_'.$value['photo1'],true));

(36, options ,fprit, 'AutoSalon/hasi/BB_Light_House_8.png', '2016/02/03/thumb_BB_Light_House_8.png', 1454520313);
```

BUT there is no File in /file/2016/02/03/thumb_BB_Light_House_8.png

```
GET http://kukur.dev/file/2016/02/03/thumb_BB_Light_House_8_1.png 404 (Not Found)
```

Here is LOG FILE

{"errorTrace":"#0 /Users/flakerimi/Sites/ImpressPages/Ip/Internal/Repository/ReflectionModel.php(60): Ip\Internal\Repository\ReflectionModel->createReflectionRecord('AutoSalon/hasi/', Array, NULL)\n#1 /Users/flakerimi/Sites/ImpressPages/Ip/Internal/Repository/ReflectionService.php(84): Ip\Internal\Repository\ReflectionModel->getReflection('AutoSalon/hasi/', Array, NULL, true)\n#2 /Users/flakerimi/Sites/ImpressPages/Ip/Functions.php(957): Ip\Internal\Repository\ReflectionService->getReflection('AutoSalon/hasi/', Array, NULL, true)\n#3 /Users/flakerimi/Sites/ImpressPages/Plugin/AutoSalon/view/user/list.php(25): ipReflection('AutoSalon/hasi/', Array)\n#4 /Users/flakerimi/Sites/ImpressPages/Ip/View.php(111): require('/Users/flakerim...')\n#5 /Users/flakerimi/Sites/ImpressPages/Ip/Application.php(352): Ip\View->render()\n#6 /Users/flakerimi/Sites/ImpressPages/Ip/Application.php(442): Ip\Application->handleRequest(Object(Ip\Request), Array, false)\n#7 /Users/flakerimi/Sites/ImpressPages/Ip/script/run.php(8): Ip\Application->run()\n#8 /Users/flakerimi/Sites/ImpressPages/index.php(14): require_once('/Users/flakerim...')\n#9 {main}"}

Comment: Where does "thumb_" come from in reflection url? Maybe that's the issue?

Comment: Forgot some part ipFileUrl(ipReflection('AutoSalon/'.$user['username'].'/'.$value['photo1'],$options,'thumb_'.$value['photo1'],true));

Comment: Its interesting that its not working only on SiteController::list() on SiteController::edit() works fine. I can make a fix, but I really want to understand why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for Archive purpose:

Problem was with $options,

```
$options = array('type' => 'center', 'widht' => 400, 'height'=>200,  'forced' => true);
```

There is a typo at Width (widht) and thats why. Maybe some better check on that ?